# Creating excel template 2003 in C# on a machine with both 2003 and 2007 installed

Tags: c#, .net, excel-2007, excel-2003

I have both 2003 and 2007 Excel versions installed on my machine.
The current source code uses Office11 (2003) interop assembly Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll to create the Excel template.

When I create the template and open in Excel 2007, it opens perfectly.
The same template when I open in 2003 I get the message "File format is not valid".

```
_excel = new Excel.Application();
_workbooks = _excel.Workbooks;
_excel.Visible = false;

_excel.DisplayAlerts = false;

// create and add a workbook with 1 worksheet named "Sheet1" 
_workbook = _workbooks.Add(Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);

_sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)_workbook.ActiveSheet;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have both versions of the interop assemblies installed, you probably have a binding redirect assembly which is redirecting Office11 calls to Office12 assemblies.

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx):

> When you install and register the
> Office PIAs in the global assembly
> cache (either with Office or by
> installing the redistributable package
> for the PIAs), the binding redirect
> assemblies are also installed only in
> the global assembly cache. These
> assemblies help make sure that the
> correct version of the primary interop
> assemblies are loaded at run time. For
> example, when a solution that
> references a 2007 Microsoft Office
> primary interop assembly runs on a
> computer that has the Microsoft Office
> 2010 version of the same primary
> interop assembly, the binding redirect
> assembly instructs the .NET Framework
> runtime to load the Microsoft Office
> 2010 version of the primary interop
> assembly. For more information, see
> Assembly Binding Redirection.

This would mean that your code is invoking Excel 2007 and therefore creating an Excel 2007 format file, which Excel 2003 can't read (without a conversion plugin).